# How to consume a WCF Service in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I am trying to call a WCF service from a windows phone 8.1 app, the option to add a service reference no longer exists.

I tried this:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://serverURl/serviceName.svc/methodName?variableName=value");
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
string data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

But it didnt work, the string is always empty.

**N.B** The server is also not local host so im not facing the problem of connecting from windows phone emulator to local host.

Comment: How to tried this code..?   that means in which file you are kept this code

Comment: You have add connected services to your app..for that you have to create mobile service in your azure service..

Answer (score 2):

Try this.
If its not working, let me know.

```
HttpClient httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
 HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get,"http://localhost:18362/Service1.svc/GetData");
 HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
 string data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
 var dialog = new MessageDialog(data);
 await dialog.ShowAsync();
```

Comment: How do you access the method in the service using this approach?

Comment: this code is not used in service..this is an exmple to how to access services in windows phone 8.1 runtime apps

Answer (score 1):

Windows Phone Store apps in Windows Phone 8.1 do not support the System.ServiceModel namespace.

There is a workaround you can

Read [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/myamama/archive/2014/06/24/workaround-to-adding-service-reference-to-windows-phone-8-1-runtime-app.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can use System.Net.Http :

```
public async Task<string> GetMethod(string url)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var response = await client.GetAsync(url); // The Get Process to get result from WCF service
        string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); // Get Json string result
        return result;
        }
    }
```